# Calculadora Decimal a Binario JS/HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, input-type

tengo un pequeño problema con mi código intentando hacerlo corto me decidí por usar parseInt para luego pasarlo por un toString(2) y completar la conversión numérica pero siempre responde NaN y no entiendo el porque de esto, si me pueden ayudar por favor eso me ayudaría a aprender y a avanzar como programador.

```js
let convertToD = document.getElementById('convertToD');

convertToD.onclick = function decToBin() {
  let decimal = Number.parseInt(document.getElementById('decimalInput'));
  document.getElementById('numCovertB').innerHTML = decimal.toString(2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container" id="de">
    <h2>Decimal a Binario</h2>
    <input type="text" name="decimalInput" class="decimalInput">
    <input id="convertToD" type="button" value="Convert">
    <p class="in" id="numCovertB">Numero Binario</p>
  </div>

</body>
<script src="js/binary.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás haciendo doble conversión numérica aquí:

```
let decimal = Number.parseInt(document.getElementById('decimalInput'));
```

De la cual sería incorrecto, debería ser:

```
let decimal = Number(document.getElementById('decimalInput'));
```

También, estás declarando a `convertToD` fuera de la función, este debe estar dentro, ya que cuando se ejecuta la función `decToBin` en el evento clic del botón, el valor de la variable `convertToD` no se actualiza, y siempre permanecerá en 0. Estructurando bien tu código, quedaría de la siguiente forma (te explico en comentarios):

```js
let botton = document.getElementById('botton'); // obtengo al botón

botton.onclick = function decToBin() { // cuando hago clic al botón, ejecuto la función...
  let convertToD = document.getElementById('convertToD').value; // y capturo el valor del input...
  let decimal = Number(convertToD); // al valor lo convierto a numérico...
  document.getElementById('in').innerHTML = decimal.toString(2); // y muestro el resultado en el id "in".
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="de">
  <h2>Decimal a Binario</h2>
  <input type="number" step="any" id="convertToD" />
  <input type="button" id="botton" value="Convert" />
  <p id="in">Numero Binario</p>
</div>
```

Comment: gracias ya entendí mis errores no conocía tampoco la propiedad step me ayudaste a entender varias cosas.

Comment: @hawiezaki Me alegro, el atributo `step="any"` es para permitir decimales en un input que es de `type="number"`.

Answer (score 0):

`Number.parseInt` recibe una cadena de texto. Le estás enviando un objeto. Lo que tienes que enviarle es la propiedad `value` de ese objeto (que devuelve el texto de la caja de texto):

```
convertToD.onclick = function decToBin() {
  let decimal = Number.parseInt(document.getElementById('convertToD').value);
  document.getElementById('numCovertB').innerHTML = decimal.toString(2);
}
```

Comment: ahora me da este error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')
    at HTMLInputElement.decToBin (binary.js:2:74)

Comment: @hawiezaki faltaba algo: la caja de texto de la que tomas el valor se llama `convertToD`. Ya lo cambié en la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Tenias varios errores en algunos puntos cómo son en el body en el control input type textbox no tenias el id y en el código del javascript te faltaba poner el value y tampoco servia el Number delante del parseInt...

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
      <title>Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>

      <div class="container" id="de">
        <h2>Decimal a Binario</h2>
        <input type="text" id="decimalInput" name="decimalInput" class="decimalInput" />
        <input id="convertToD" type="button" value="Convert" />
        <p class="in" id="numCovertB">Numero Binario</p>
      </div>


    <script>
    let convertToD = document.getElementById('convertToD');

    convertToD.onclick = function decToBin() {
      let decimal = parseInt(document.getElementById('decimalInput').value);
      document.getElementById('numCovertB').innerHTML = decimal.toString(2);
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```